# Run .Rmd posts on HUGO's Academic theme?

Tags: r-markdown, hugo

Anyone knows a way to publish .Rmd files on Academic's Theme on HUGO? Normally .md and HTML files are easily read by Academic theme but when it comes to .Rmd they are nowhere to be found in the post. I can't find a way to make my website react to

**This is a portion of my config.toml**, which I thought may have something to do:

```
paginate = 10 # Number of items per page in paginated lists.
enableEmoji = true
footnotereturnlinkcontents = "<sup>^</sup>"
ignoreFiles = [".ipynb$", ".ipynb_checkpoints$", "_files$", "_cache$"]
[outputs]
home = [ "HTML", "RSS", "JSON", "WebAppManifest" ]
section = [ "HTML", "RSS" ]
[mediaTypes."application/manifest+json"]
suffixes = ["webmanifest"]
[outputFormats.WebAppManifest]
mediaType = "application/manifest+json"
rel = "manifest"
```

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

A list of supported file formats in hugo can be found [here](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/). As you can see `.Rmd` is not among them. `.Rmd` files have to be `.html` (or `.md`) in order to be understood and rendered by hugo.

If you use blogdown and run the command `blogdown::serve_site()` instead of usual cli `hugo server` this should be done automatically, if I am not mistaken.

Best